# react-native browser console logging for json object

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Hi my browser console sometimes logs the correct format while other times it abbreviates json objects. for example sometimes it will log my redux state object as

> Object { accessToken: "", idToken: "" }

while on other screens it will just say

> [object Object]

. Any explanations on why? How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects) recommends:

Don't use `console.log(obj);`,
use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));`.